# Strapi file upload does not recognize AWS-S3

Tags: amazon-s3, strapi

I am working with "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.18.2"

For your reference my package json looks like this:

```
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "koa-router": "^9.0.1",
    "objection": "^2.1.3",
    "pg": "^8.0.3",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.1",
    "strapi": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-admin": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.0.0-beta.18.2",
    "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3": "^3.0.2",
    "strapi-utils": "3.0.0-beta.18.2"
```

Uploading locally works perfect, but now I am trying to deploy to heroku.

When I try to upload a file I keep getting the following error:

```
The provider package isn't installed. Please run npm install strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3
```

I also get in the console, the following:

```
http://localhost:1337/content-manager/explorer/application::promotion.promotion/11 400 (Bad Request)
```

As you can see the package is already installed. I have checked and my app is running with productions settings.

Any idea what can be? this is giving me an strong headache.

I have also trying updating strapi version but it breaks my app.

Comment: I have the exact problem but using the [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/Lith/strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud-storage) provider instead of AWS-S3: Error: The provider package isn't installed. Please run `npm install strapi-provider-upload-google-cloud`

I wonder if its because of npm, I will try installing everything with yarn.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than [Alejandro Sanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8138266/alejandro-sanchez). The problem is that strapi is searching the provider name directly inside the upload object, not in upload.config and without the 'strapi-provider-upload' part in the name. This solution should work (replace gcp by aws depending on the case):

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    provider: 'google-cloud-storage',
    providerOptions: {
      bucketName: env("GCS_BUCKET_NAME"),
      publicFiles: true,
      uniform: true,
      basePath: ""
    },
    },
  });
```

Pay attention i removed the 'strapi-provider-upload' part in the config file. Same for aws, should be:
`aws-s3` besides `strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3`